# PHP Nested foreach with Key

Tags: php, foreach, key, skyscanner

I have been trying to work this out for two days now and am hitting a brick wall. I have a skyscanner array that has flight itineraries where I have the flight

```
Leg - being Itineraries -> OutboundLegId -
```

and also the legs which shows the flight number - being

```
Legs -> FlightNumbers -> FlightNumber.
```

What I am trying to achieve is to display the Itinerary and then join the Flight Number on to that. But no matter what I try I cannot get this to work. I have read all about Keys on here and tried loads of examples but am coming up with nothing. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Example arrays below

```
[Itineraries] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [OutboundLegId] => 13542-1610140610-29-0-13445-1610141240
            [InboundLegId] => 13445-1610211340-29-0-13542-1610211640
            [PricingOptions] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [Agents] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 2174187
                                )

                            [QuoteAgeInMinutes] => 31
                            [Price] => 200.98
                            [DeeplinkUrl] => http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/deeplink/v2?_cje=5JlLCgyPUKY0hT8T0Ybh6dL0Xf0htAiHTFX7RU79eeI3XvrsxvEqP1QUJAoHiHRd&url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.apideeplink.com%2ftransport_deeplink%2f4.0%2fUK%2fen-gb%2fGBP%2fcook%2f2%2f13542.13445.2016-10-14%2c13445.13542.2016-10-21%2fair%2fairli%2fflights%3fitinerary%3dflight%7c-32294%7c1152%7c13542%7c2016-10-14T06%3a10%7c13445%7c2016-10-14T12%3a40%2cflight%7c-32294%7c1153%7c13445%7c2016-10-21T13%3a40%7c13542%7c2016-10-21T16%3a40%26carriers%3d-32294%26passengers%3d1%2c0%2c0%26channel%3ddataapi%26cabin_class%3deconomy%26facilitated%3dfalse%26ticket_price%3d200.98%26is_npt%3dfalse%26is_multipart%3dfalse%26client_id%3dskyscanner_b2b%26request_id%3d3bc96bda-fd7c-403a-b841-2ccc3c26071d%26commercial_filters%3dfalse%26q_datetime_utc%3d2016-09-29T08%3a18%3a27
                        )

[Legs] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 13542-1610140610-29-0-13445-1610141240
            [SegmentIds] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

            [OriginStation] => 13542
            [DestinationStation] => 13445
            [Departure] => 2016-10-14T06:10:00
            [Arrival] => 2016-10-14T12:40:00
            [Duration] => 270
            [JourneyMode] => Flight
            [Stops] => Array
                (
                )

            [Carriers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 105
                )

            [OperatingCarriers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 105
                )

            [Directionality] => Outbound
            [FlightNumbers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [FlightNumber] => 1152
                            [CarrierId] => 105
                        )

                )

        )
```

Comment: Please provide example of result that you want to achieve

Comment: Only link between the two I can see is the first 5 numbers of the leg id and the origin/destination station. The rest seems like it comes from somewhere else for the resulting array. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I simply need to join the two arrays on Itineraries -> OutboundLegId and Legs -> Id so I can then retrieve the flight number. I have a foreach loop which is looping through all the itineraries with no problem - but I don't understand how to join the second array

Comment: Itineraries -> OutboundLegId and Legs -> Id are the same

Comment: Are these 2 seperate arrays or do they all exist in one big array

Comment: @Dean can you use array_column for Legs array and join with array_map?

Comment: I can use whatever you suggest @Dmytrechko but I am not sure how to implement - can you point me in the right direction?. I thought OutboundLegId as a key but am just going round in circles. Also this is one long piece of json from skyscanner Riggs, I have just cropped it for the pertinent bits

Comment: Ok, try this - it should join proper leg in 'legs' key in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is one big array and its called `$data` you can nest a couple of foreach loops.

I use foreach loops as I assume there are cases where this data structure get more complex than the one you show

```
foreach ( $data['Itineraries'] as $itin ) {

    foreach ( $data['Legs'] as $legs) {
        if ($legs['Id'] == $itin['OutboundLegId']) {

            // we matched the itinerary with a leg
            echo $legs['OutboundLegId'] . ' ' . $legs['FlightNumbers'][0]['FlightNumber'];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use array_column to sort one of your arrays - it allows you to get rid or nested foreach.
See example with sorted legs.

Comment: @Dmytrechko I am assuming that if this question has to be asked, something as elegant as your answer will just baffle the OP, so I opted for simplicity

Comment: Ha ha. Yes simplicity is the key guys :-) I shall give both a go and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree with you about baffling. I just try to avoid unnecessary iterations. And if your solution will work for OP - you can offer alternative option. 
P.S. But question about performance still open. I'm not sure whether it will be efficient to use array_column instead of foreach.

Comment: Hi Riggs I tried this and while it doesn't throw an error it doesn't return any data (the array is called $array by the way :-) )

Comment: Tweaked it. Works!! Thanks Riggs

Comment: I can't as I don't have enough rep to make a change to one character

Comment: By the way it was simply a capital I in $legs['id']

Comment: @Dean Amended accordingly, assumed it was more serious than that.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as draft. Can't  perform function without feedback.
Put proper arrays instead of {YOUR-ARRAY-WITH-LEGS} and {YOUR-ARRAY-WITH-ITINERARIES}

```
$sortedLegs = array_column('Id', {YOUR-ARRAY-WITH-LEGS});

$joinedArray = array_map(function($itinerary) use($sortedLegs){
    if(array_key_exists($itinerary['OutboundLegId'],$sortedLegs)) {
        $itinerary['legs'] = $sortedLegs[$itinerary['OutboundLegId']];
    }
  return $itinerary;
},{YOUR-ARRAY-WITH-ITINERARIES});
```

Comment: This throws an error Dmytrechko. My array is called $array if that helps?

Comment: So for {YOUR-ARRAY-WITH-LEGS} would I replace with {$array['Legs']['Id']} with $array being the array name?

Comment: If I understood properly about your structure:
Instead of {YOUR-ARRAY-WITH-LEGS} use $array['Legs'];
Instead of {YOUR-ARRAY-WITH-ITINERARIES} use $array['Itineraries'];
Without curly braces

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't work. Appreciate your help though